# Calculate mean of array with specific value from another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have these numpy arrays:

```
array1 = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2])
array2 = np.array([34.2, 11.2, 22.1, 78.2, 55.0, 66.87, 33.3, 11.56])
```

Now I want to return a 2d array in which there is the mean for each distinctive value from array1 so my output would look something like this:

```
array([[-1, 22.7],
       [ 1, 55.7],
       [ 2, 33.3]])
```

Is there an efficient way without concatenating those 1D arrays to one 2D array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)  -

```
# Get unique array1 elems, tag them starting from 0 and get their tag counts
unq,ids,count = np.unique(array1,return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)

# Use the tags/IDs to perform ID based summation of array2 elems and 
# thus divide by the ID counts to get ID based average values
out = np.column_stack((unq,np.bincount(ids,array2)/count))
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: array1 = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2])
    ...: array2 = np.array([34.2, 11.2, 22.1, 78.2, 55.0, 66.87, 33.3, 11.56])
    ...: 

In [18]: out
Out[18]: 
array([[ -1.        ,  22.7       ],
       [  1.        ,  55.72333333],
       [  2.        ,  33.28666667]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical grouping operation, and the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides extensions to numpy to perform these type of operations efficiently and concisely:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
groups, means = npi.group_by(array_1).mean(array_2)
```

Note that you can in this manner easily perform other kind of reductions as well, such as a median for example.